# Nuxt JS SSR title undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt JS/Vue to create an SEO friendly Server Side Rendered JS web app. Nuxt allows setting the `head` option in each Vue component which it then take and via `vue-meta` updates the page title. I get a user based on the route and then set the `title` to the user's name. This works when running a local server. But when I push this up to Firebase I get the `title` as undefined (on refresh).

Vue Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="user">
    <h3>{{ name }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'test'
    }
  },
  head () {
    return {
      title: this.name,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: 'My custom description'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  async asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${+params.id}`)
      return data
    } catch (e) {
      error({ message: 'User not found', statusCode: 404 })
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.name)
    this.title = this.name
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: As far as I know you should be using a layout file for this.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Will report back if I find anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same issue and I solved using this. Add the below code in your page in script tag under export default {}.

```
head () {
        return {
            title: this.metaTitle,
            meta: [
                { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: this.metaDescription },
                { name: 'keywords', content: this.metaTags},
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old tread, but I just wanted to give some reasoning on the matter.. You can use both solutions:

`head: {
  title : ''
}`

`head() {
  return { 
    title: '' 
  }`

BUT the difference between them is that when you use head as a property you won't be able to access `this` or any property you set in `asyncData` or `data` methods, you will only be limited to text in main lines. The reason is that when you use it as a property it gets populated when the component gets constructed, which is actually before the data is set (on the server)

When you use it as a method `head()` and return an object with the standart vue-meta properties, you can access `data()` and `asyncData()` set properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nuxt 3 then you can define your title 3 way

1. **Globaly** in ***nuxt.config.ts/js*** file

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
   meta: {
       title: "Nuxt 3",
   }
})
```

2. **Localy** into .vue files 
   a. Form  `<script setup> useMeta({ title: 'ROAST - Home' }) </script>` 
   b. Into template tag(under 1st div):

   ```
   <template>
      <div>
        <Head> 
          <Title>Nuxt 3</Title>
        </Head>
      </div>
   </template>
   ```